# Profile Pages - URL Parameter

Tags: php, mysql, url-parameters

I have made this code:

```
    <?php
    if (isset($_GET['name'])) {
        $username = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['name']);
        if (ctype_alnum($username)) {
            //check user exists
            $check = mysql_query("SELECT user, bio, permisos FROM usuarios WHERE user='$user'");
            if (mysql_num_rows($check)===1) {
            $get = mysql_fetch_assoc($check);
            $userA = $get['user'];
            $bio = $get['bio']; 
            $permission = $get['permisos']; 
        }
        else
        {
            Header("Location: invalid.php");    
            exit();
        }
        }
    }                                

?>
```

'permisos' means permission,
'usuarios' means users

I am trying to make a profile page with parameters to access the page. The parameter will look like this: /profile.php?name=username.

Comment: What is the goal to be precise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first error is in the query:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT user, bio, permisos FROM usuarios WHERE user='$user'");
```

You don't have variable `$user` defined anywhere, it should be `$username`

You should also rather use `mysqli` functions and not deprecated `mysql` functions and the better option will be prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote $user instead of $username(you are getting value in $username). Correct this line

```
  $check = mysql_query("SELECT user, bio, permisos FROM usuarios WHERE user='$user'");
```

with

```
 $check = mysql_query("SELECT user, bio, permisos FROM usuarios WHERE user='$username'");
```

Answer (score 0):

check query. write `$username` instead of `$user`